# Limit matlab calculations preciseness

Tags: matlab, rounding, rounding-error

In my numerical analysis class we sometimes need to do calculations with t-digit rounding arithmetics, i.e. every calculation (**every** calculation, not every variable assignment) is rounded to t meaning-full digits. I'm using matlab for my calculations, and I need a way to limit matlab to do **all** of its calculations in t-digit rounding arithmetics.

If no such way exist, I would want to find a way to round specific number to t meaning-full digits.

Thanks!

p.s. I tried using `digits(t)` but it seems to effect only the way matlab display the numbers (I may be using it wrong).

Comment: In my assignment I need to solve a linear system Ax=b using elimination, with 3-digit round arithmetic. I don't think this is too absurd, this what happened in "real life" but with 32 or 64 digits (if I'm not wrong). This meant to emphasise this phenomenon

Comment: In addition to `vpa`  (as mentioned by @user2305193) you can also use the [Fixed Point Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/index.html).  Neither are in base MATLAB - i.e. they are in add-on Toolboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 system_dependent('setprecision',24); %accepts values 24, 53 or 64
```

as described in [this](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function) and [this](http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/155369) resource.